# mvc 5 browse icon missing on window phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I created a blank MVC 5 app - changed nothing.
After publishing everthy works fine - except that I get no "navigation icon" on my WP8 device.
I get a (small font) full navigation bar on a WP7 device.
I get the icon on a galaxy tab.

But on my WP8 device (tested with mobile as well as with desktop setting in IE) I get nothing.
If I switch to landscape I see the "About" and "Contact" links but not "Register / Login".
When I turn back to portrait - "About" and "Contact" are visible till I refresh the page.
Then they are gone again.

The device I tested with is a Lumia 1020 WP8 (8.0.10517.150) German (768 x 1280).
I got some screenshots with the results:
[image: Landscape scrooled]

[image: Landscape 2]
[image: Portrait]

As you can see - no "Menu box" on the right.
I also checked it with a Lumia 920 (WP8) - same results.

Comment: would you mind sharing the relevant part of the generated HTML ( generated by your MVC project) ?

Comment: I can't, since I have no idea how to get the source on my WP8 device.

Comment: The HTML is the same both on your desktop and WP8, therefore you can copy it from your desktop browser or dev environment.

Comment: Sorry for that - I just published the site so you can check this http://ball.sol-city.net/

By the way this is "as it comes" - I created a new WebProject  / MVC in VS2013 - built and published - no modifications at all!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a working solution.
After finding this link http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/ I checked other the (there linked)article at http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html

Adding (found at "Update: January 15 2013) the script

```
(function() {
if ("-ms-user-select" in document.documentElement.style && navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}")
    );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
```

})();

fixed the problem for me.